# Capture HTTP request headers / parameters using BrowserMob Proxy and selenium web driver using perl client

Tags: perl, selenium, browsermob-proxy

I'm trying to capture http request parameters using Selenium::Remote::Driverand Browsermob::Proxy. The pseudo code is as below. I couldn't get the http headers.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
use Data::Dumper;

my $proxy = Browsermob::Proxy->new(trace => 2);
my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new(
browser_name => 'firefox',
proxy        => $proxy->selenium_proxy(1)
);

$proxy->new_har( payload => {
        initialPageRef => '1' }, captureHeaders => 'true',
    captureContent => 'true',
    captureBinaryContent => 'true');

$driver->get('http://www.google.com/');
print Dumper($proxy->har);
```

UPDATE:

1. The module Net::HTTP::Spore::Role::Middleware uses a deprecated method (Class::MOP::load_class). I changed it to Class::Load::load_class
2. The argument 'httpProxy' to Selenium::Remote::Driver has to be specific IP address without URL scheme. If it is $proxy->selenium_proxy, it is not working.

However, I could capture only first request. The subsequent requests that selenium drive makes couldn't be captured. For example, the below code captures only the first GET request not the second one.

```
use Data::Dumper;
use Browsermob::Proxy;
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;

my $proxy = Browsermob::Proxy->new(
server_port => 8080,
);


$proxy->new_har( payload => {
        initialPageRef => 'payload is optional' }, captureHeaders => 'true',
    captureContent => 'true',
    captureBinaryContent => 'true', port => $proxy->port );

my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new(
browser_name => 'firefox',
proxy        =>  { 'proxyType' => 'manual', 'httpProxy' =>     '127.0.0.1:'.$proxy->port}, 
);
$driver->get('http://www.google.com/');
$driver->find_element("//input[\@name='q']")->send_keys("selenium");
$driver->find_element("//button[\@name='btnG']")->click;
print Dumper($proxy->har);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `create_new_har` instead of `new_har`.

```
$proxy->create_new_har(
    payload => {
        initialPageRef => 'payload is optional'
    },
    captureHeaders => 'true',
    captureContent => 'true',
    captureBinaryContent => 'true'
);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But It doesn't work. I don't get http parameters

Comment: @Pathak, Please find the output as below.

Comment: $VAR1 = {
 'log' => {
 'entries' => [],
 'version' => '1.2',
 'pages' => [
 {
 'startedDateTime' => '2016-05-20T19:02:34.105-05:00',
 'title' => 'Page 0',
 'comment' => '',
 'id' => 'Page 0',
 'pageTimings' => {
 'comment' => ''
 }
 }
 ],
 'creator' => {
 'name' => 'BrowserMob Proxy',
 'comment' => '',
 'version' => '2.1.0-beta-6-littleproxy'
 },
 'comment' => ''
 }
 };